How to run a container after another container is up and running?
I need to run 2 docker containers using the following docker-compose.yaml file. The first container is a juice-shop app and the second one is supposed to be a Test-Project which checks the juice-shop features.
version: '3.8'

services:
  juice-shop:
    image: bkimminich/juice-shop
    container_name: juice-shop
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    networks:
      test-net:
        aliases:
          - juice-shop-service
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", "curl -f -X GET http://juice-shop-service:3000/rest/products/search?q= || exit 1"]
      interval: 10s
      retries: 5
      start_period: 30s
      timeout: 5s

  integration-tests:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: integration-tests
    depends_on:
      juice-shop:
        condition: service_healthy
    networks:
      - test-net

networks:
  test-net:
    driver: bridge

To make the problem easy to understand, you can consider the below Dockerfile for building the Integration-Test container:
# Use an official Maven image as a parent image
FROM maven:3.8.7-openjdk-18

# Install needed tool for debuging
RUN microdnf update -y && \
    microdnf install -y curl iputils && \
    microdnf clean all



RUN mvn --version

# Keep container alive
CMD ["tail", "-f", "/dev/null"]

I expect the integration-tests service starts only once the juice-shop is up and running. In that case the result of below HTTP GET request should be 200:
"http://juice-shop-service:3000/rest/products/search?q="

The problem is, when i run the docker compose up i get the below error:
dependency failed to start: container juice-shop is unhealthy
The picture from Docker Desktop shows that two containers have been created, but the integration-test container isn't running. However, I know the juice-shop container is working because I can access the app in my browser at http://localhost:3000/#/.


Have you tried to increase retries: and timeout :?

no, but when sleep the integration test for 120 seconds then everything works well

You should be able to replicate the health check running docker-compose exec juice-shop sh -c 'curl ... || exit 1'; does that give any hints as to what might be going wrong?

Inspect the juice-shop container to see the results of the healtcheck.

You should use localhost as the hostname in the URL in your healthcheck since you're making the request to the container itself.
